# How to find AD user Login details

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have active directory configured in windows server 2012 r2. I want to collect logs of a particular user or Multiple users. The logs must show the login time, logout time, system operating system, IP address etc of last 10 days or more.  How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done an Internet search for ideas? Please edit these answers into your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's some good scripts in the Script Centre for this type of stuff. This one may suit your needs: http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/89-track-login-and-logout-vbs﻿

How to Audit Successful Logon/Logoff and Failed Logons in Active Directory
https://www.lepide.com/blog/audit-successful-logon-logoff-and-failed-logons-in-activedirectory/

If you just want the last login for each user then use:

@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^|find "IP Address"') do call :process %%a & goto :next
:next
echo You are on subnet %subnet% with address %ipaddress%
echo %date%,%time%,%computername%,%username%,%ipaddress% >\server\share$\lastuser\%computername%.txt

exit /b

:process
  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%1") do (set subnet=%%a.%%b.%%c)&(set host=%%d)&(set network=%%c)
  set ipaddress=%subnet%.%host%
exit /b

Then add a shortcut on your desktop or whatever to a batch file as:

type \server\share$\lastuser*.txt > "%temp%\allcomputers.csv"
start excel "%temp%\allcomputers.csv"

http://www.rlmueller.net/Logon5.htm